# Implementing Azure AD B2C on Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, azure-ad-b2c, msal.js

I am stuck configuring Azure AD B2C for an ionic app. I have a working web app that uses MSAL.js, but when I configure it for a mobile app (ionic) nothing happens when I click/tap on social buttons like "Facebook"... I would appreciate any links/guidance that will help solve the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the 0.7.1 / 0.7.2-dev versions of the ADAL Cordova plugin use ADAL libraries that do not meet the B2C handshake / Oauth2 requirements. Using the ADAL [Cordova Plugin](https://github.com/jospete/azure-activedirectory-library-for-cordova) Patch For B2C and [angular-jwt](https://github.com/auth0/angular-jwt), we can implement Azure AD B2C Sign In On Cordova/Ionic App

Comment: Hi Marliee, thanks for the response. I am wondering if there are any plans to add B2C handshake/Oauth2 support to ADAL libraries? I am not sure if I can use the patch for my project.